# resizableImageWithCapInsets: issues

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I try to figure out how to fit dropdown image into black border (border just for cenvenience) in `UIImageView` using `resizableImageWithCapInsets:`.

I use AutoLayout, `_imageView` has fixed height constraint

```
        UIImage *dropdown = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"dropdown.png"]
                         resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 20, 0, 100)];
        _imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; // modes see below
        _imageView.clipsToBounds = NO;
        _imageView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
        _imageView.image = dropdown;
```

`UIViewContentModeTopLeft`

[image: top left]

`UIViewContentModeScaleToFill`

[image: scale to fill]

`UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit`

[image: aspect fit]

`UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill`

[image: aspect fill]

**Edit**

I tried setting top and bottom insets as advised by @Rahul and what I get now if setting `UIViewContentModeScaleToFill` (similar results in other modes). As you may notice, the white down-arrow in now shifted slightly down

```
UIImage *dropdown = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"dropdown.png"]
                         resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 20, 8, 100)];
```

[image: other pic]

**Edit 2**

Changing offsets seems not to help here, problem seems to be in vertical scaling, as if image view acceps only one vertical offset for some reason, not both, so we get non-symmetric vertical offset

**Edit 3**

Example project on GitHub: [ScaleTest-iOS](https://github.com/schmidt9/ScaleTest-iOS)

**Edit 4**

Updated GitHub example with custom resizing methods (no avail though), created [topic](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63288) on Apple Dev Forum

**Edit 5**

Accepted answer I see as a workaround, really I'd prefer to keep fixed height, but it seems to be not possible. Anyway, thanks to @Rahul for assistance.

Comment: I'm confused - haven't you answered your own question in the second picture? EDIT: I see now. The bottom is truncated. Never mind me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer this tutorial: [How To Make A Stretchable Button With UIEdgeInsetsMake](https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-stretchable-button-uiedgeinsetsmake/) for `UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 8, 8, 8)` & apply  suitable edge insets for your image....

```
UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"dropdown"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 20, 8, 100)];
_imageView4.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
_imageView4.clipsToBounds = NO;
_imageView4.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
_imageView4.image = image;
```

Set the **imageview4** height 35 instead 40 pixels & then works perfect...

[image]

Comment: I tried it, all in vain, problem seems to be in vertical image scaling, dont know why image view scales my image so weird

Comment: UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 20, 8, 100) is Scaling Vertically set properly, but Scaling Horizontally is not the proper means UIEdgeInsetsMake(top, 20, bottom, 100). Change top & bottom value....

Comment: See my updated question, I tried setting top and bottom to 8, arrow shifts down while it should stay in the middle vertically

Comment: So what values should I set?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123501/discussion-between-rahul-and-schmidt9).

Answer (score 0):

```
_imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit; 
_imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 20; // Apply your required value.
_imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Thanks but it is not what I want, it does not help to fit image into bounds

Comment: Then sorry I did not understand your question. :-)

Comment: As Apple Documents on [UIImageView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimageview) specified, `contentMode` should be `ScaleToFill` when using stretchable image.

Answer (score 0):

try this UIEdgeInsetsMake(8, 100, 8, 8); use 20px if your image border curve has radius of 20px

Comment: 20 is too much, arrow is being distorted

Comment: updated  code as it seems that your border radius is around 8 px, , and if right arrow button with Brown background is of 100px width then use 100. and right need not be stratched so its 100.

Comment: left and right insets are alright, see my updated question, top and bottom insets 8 (or whatever) lead to arrow being shifted down